# show the process in a football feint or motion

Tags: editing

I am a football coach and need to make some videos over some exercises.
Here I would like to have some kind of "line" through the movement itself.

If you look at this little 5-6 sec. clips from 1 min and 40 sec. then it's something like what I think on [CRAZY STRONG FITNESS MOMENTS - Youtube](https://youtu.be/XnzQRPdunTE?t=100).

[image]

I agree that it is a clip where you have then taken some frames, which must be shown layer-on-layer from the tail and then removed when the video reaches the actual "movement" but are there any who can confirm this or know tutorials on how-to?

Answer (score 1):

You would do this kind of thing in After-Effects or a similar compositing program (like Nuke or Fusion). Simply duplicate your video as many times as you want the move to be repeated, then offset the layers in time, and lastly roughly mask out the person from every shot except the very bottom layer.